# Can I make api calls inside React Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it a good idea to make api calls inside **React Context Provider**?

```
const SomeContext = createContext({
    data: {},
});

const SomeProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

  const data = fetch(url);

  return (<SomeContext.Provider value={{ data }}>
    {children}
  </SomeContext.Provider>)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do anything inside the provider, just I would create an additional function to pass to your provider, so that you can call for a re-fetch anytime.

e.g.

```
const SomeProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
     const fetchValues = await fetch(data);
     setData(fetchValues)
  }


  return (<SomeContext.Provider value={{ data, fetchData }}>
    {children}
  </SomeContext.Provider>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `SomeProvider` is not actually a provider; it is simply a component that *uses* a context provider.
You can do anything inside this component that you would do in any other React component. Ideally, you want to use hooks (see [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)) to handle API requests in your components, though:

```js
const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // called once, when the component loads
    const response = await fetch(url)
    setData(response)
  }, [])

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ data }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  )
}
```